# Convert Cursor Coordinates

Tags: c#

I have this code which converts the **X** coordinate of the mouse cursor in a `float` value:

```
    private float XToFloat(int x)
    {
        return (float)(x / (float)this.Width);
    }
```

the result is something like this **0.01234567** now how can i convert that back to the original coordinate? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Its just a simple mathematics. using the code.

```
private float XToFloat(int x)
{
   return (float)(x / (float)this.Width);
}
```

Example:

```
//If Width Value
this.Width = 10;
```

calling the function and passing a value to the parameter like `XToFloat(5);`
the function will return a value of **0.5**.

```
//inside the function
    (float)(x / (float)this.Width); => (float)(5 / (float)10);
//z = x/y
```

to convert that back to the original value we create a function we multiply the float value to the Width.

```
private int FloatToX(float f){
        return (int)((float)this.Width*f);
    }
```

Example is `FloatToX(0.5)` **0.5x10** will return an integer value of **5**

```
//inside the function
    (int)((float)this.Width*f) => (int)((float)10*0.5)
//x = zy
```

in mathematics its just

to get z

```
z = x/y
```

to get x

```
x = zy
```

to get y

```
y = x/z
```

Comment: While it is fitting to your username, would you mind further explaining that code, or how it works a bit?

Comment: i have edit my answer. sorry not really good at explaining :)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple maths:

```
float floatValue = (float)(x / (float)this.Width);
int cursorX = floatValue * this.Width;
```

Edit: Think of the float value as a percentage. It ranges from 0 to 1, which is equivalent to 0-100%. The float version of the x coordinate is then simply a percentage of the width:

```
0%   width   100%
+-------------+
|             |
|        80%  |
|         X   |
|             |
+-------------+
```

So to get the original coordinate back you multiply the width by the percentage.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, i see now that  i should have paid attention in the math class

Answer (score 0):

Let us say this.Width as Y now

Converted value(0.01234567) as Z

so what you are doing is

```
z=x/y
```

what u want is x and u have Z this time so

```
Z*Y=X
```